# Populating JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to put the value from the json into the JTable in Swing. I am not sure how to achieve this.

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    // Read the contents of an entity and return it as a String.
                    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    System.out.println(content);
                }
```

The String content will have the below response

```
{"files": [{"size": 307, "mtime": 1510975069.357518, "name": "myTest1", 
"md5": "08321ed7e74781d149ecd28a332a5202"}, {"size": 24977837, "mtime": 
1510515489.0755424, "name": "mytest2", "md5": 
"7e3541b53bd0bb2c587fe407ad426fd4"}]}
```

In the JTable, I want dynamically to get populated when i click a button. There can be more than one rows in the table based on the response.

[image]

Comment: This post include many potential questions: How make a JTable ? How to populate it ? How to parse response ?  Do it one step and a time and ask one specific question when you have a problem.

Comment: Convert the JSON into a `List` of  POJOs, it will make it easier to represent